# Show/Hide hyperlink in datagrid based on ServerVariable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, .net-2.0, request.servervariables

I have the following in a datagrid using .NET 2:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "edit.aspx?f=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "forum_id") & "&t=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "thread_id") & "&p=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "post_id") %>' Text="Edit" ID="Hyperlink1"></asp:HyperLink>
```

At the moment, this link appears in all posts (or datagrid rows) in a simplistic forum I coded years ago.

I can detect the user using the forum with the following code:

```
Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
```

How do I show/hide the hyperlink on each post based on the `servervariable`?

So if I have 10 posts in a particular page, where 3 of those posts are by user x, how do I only show that hyperlink when user x is viewing that page, only on the posts which user x created?

Comment: Are you sure Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") is what you need ?
From MSDN : 
LOGON_USER :
 
The Windows account that the user is impersonating while connected to your Web server. Use REMOTE_USER, UNMAPPED_REMOTE_USER, or AUTH_USER to view the raw user name that is contained in the request header. The only time LOGON_USER holds a different value than these other variables is if you have an authentication filter installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding visible attribute with the following code :

```
<asp:HyperLink visible='<%# Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") == "x" %>' runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "edit.aspx?f=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "forum_id") & "&t=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "thread_id") & "&p=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "post_id") %>' Text="Edit" ID="Hyperlink1"></asp:HyperLink>
```